# Tooltwist Controller connection reset by peer

Tags: java, tomcat, controller, tooltwist

I am trying to deploy our designer using the Tooltwist Controller and I keep receiving the following error:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                          |
|                                     GENERATION PHASE                                     |
|                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
...
**
**  Check the server is running
**
Setting JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx5g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Starting the launchpad...
$ ./startup.sh
Wait a bit...
-
Error with http request: Connection reset by peer
==>> Status is error - Connection reset by peer
==>> Status is down

**
** Fatal error: Could not start the launchpad.
**

Finished: SUCCESS
```

I have tried changing the tomcat version in the payloads using both Tomcat 7.0.54 and Tomcat 7.0.40 but the issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the launchpad server is not starting correctly. There are many reasons why Tomcat might not start, so the best first step is to look at the Tomcat log file, which will be located somewhere like `/ControllerV8/launchpads/<launchpad-name>/image/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`.

One possibility could be that another launchpad's server is already running using the same launchpad ports.

Comment: Thanks Phil!  Found the error with the launchpad's web.xml being misconfigured.  The TOOLTWIST_HOME environment should point to the site-conf folder of the launchpad. e.g. /ControllerV8/launchpads/<launchpad-name>/site-conf